# Transaction Not Working As Expected in Custom Procedure

Tags: neo4j

I'm having issues when trying to issue commits using a custom procedure. I am selecting data from an external datasource, and then transforming it into a graph DB. I am trying to make each row from the external datasource it's own transaction, but if any row fails, all the transactions fail. Please let me know where I've gone wrong. Here are snippets of my code:

```
@Context
public GraphDatabaseService db;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Description("CALL myProc")
@Procedure(name = "myProc", mode = Mode.WRITE)
public void myProc() {
    // Get the last time the procedure succeeded from the System node
    try {
        boolean processAgain = true;
        int startRow = 1, endRow = 10000, batchSize = 10000;
        int total = 0, succeeded = 0, failed = 0;
        while (processAgain) {
            result = db.execute(new StringBuilder("CALL apoc.load.jdbc(\"dbAlias\", \"SQL GOES HERE\")").toString());

            while (result.hasNext()) {
                total++;
                Map<String, Object> row = result.next();
                for (String key : result.columns()) {
                    Map<String, Object> currentRow = ((Map<String, Object>) row.get(key));
                    Transaction trans = db.beginTx();
                    log.info("Beginning transaction");

                    try {
                        // Do stuff here (i.e. db.execute...)

                        trans.success();
                        succeeded++;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        failed++;
                        log.error("Error message", e);
                    } finally {
                        trans.close();
                    }
                }
            }   // End results while loop

            if (total != 0) {
                log.info(new StringBuilder("Processed ").append(total - startRow + 1).append(" rows").toString());
            }
            processAgain = total != 0 && total % endRow == 0;
            startRow += batchSize;
            endRow += batchSize;
        } // End processAgain while loop

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error message", e);
    }
}
```

UPDATE: And here's the console output

```
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
        TransactionFailureException: Transaction was marked as successful, but unable to commit transaction so rolled back.
org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Transaction was marked as successful, but unable to commit transaction so rolled back.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:100)
        at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.apps.TransactionProvidingApp.execute(TransactionProvidingApp.java:250)
        at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.apps.cypher.Start.execute(Start.java:82)
        at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractAppServer.interpretLine(AbstractAppServer.java:126)
        at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.GraphDatabaseShellServer.interpretLine(GraphDatabaseShellServer.java:105)
        at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemotelyAvailableServer.interpretLine(RemotelyAvailableServer.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.exceptions.TransactionFailureException: Transaction rolled back even if marked as successful
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.failOnNonExplicitRollbackIfNeeded(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:599)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.closeTransaction(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:541)
        at org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.Transaction.close(Transaction.java:189)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:78)
        ... 22 more
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll have to tell us what's going wrong. Do you get an error message? Does the graph just not look like what you expected? What's happening?

Comment: I updated the original post. Sorry, I should've included that originally. As far as what's happening, neither of the nodes in the DB are being updated even though only one of the transactions is unsuccessful.